# Is it possible to insert a String toType[] array?

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any way to insert a String to a Type[] array? Or Strings can be stored in String arrays?

```
Fruit[] f=new Fruit[10];
Orange a=new Orange();
f[0]=a.getName();
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? Also what do you think, would it be OK to let String be placed in Fruit array?

Comment: BTW, you can trick compiler and cast your `Fruit[]` array to `Object[]` array which can accept any object (like String), but at runtime it will throw exception because arrays check type of element before they will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a `String` can be stored in a `String` array (`String[]`) or an `Object` array (`Object[]`). If `a.getName()` returns a `String`, the assignment `f[0]=a.getName();` won't pass compilation.

Comment: So if i want to store a string and a double i can use the Object[] and there won't be any problem?

Comment: @NikosTek You can store any reference type in an Object[]. That includes a String and a Double (but not a double, which is a primitive type).

Comment: Thanks a lot Eran your help was precious.